# Is there a way to pass a variable to a document object?

Tags: javascript

I am new to this language and I am trying to call the item variable but when I call it, I get an error. I don't know if this is possible with the way I am doing it, I hope it is because it can save a lot of time.

I have tried all I can think of, but nothing has worked. I am sure that the problem has something to do with the item variable.

Here is all the code I am working with:

```
var value = 0;
var total = document.getElementById('total');
var burger_item = ['Cheeseburger', 'DCheeseburger', 'TCheeseburger', 
'Western', 'Veggie'];
var burger_price = [5.00, 7.50, 10.00, 11.50, 5.00];
function Calculate() {
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        var item = burger_item[i];
        var item_price = burger_price[i];
        var Cheeseburger = document.getElementById('Cheeseburger');
        var DCheeseburger=document.getElementById('DoubleCheeseburger');
        var TCheeseburger=document.getElementById('TripleCheeseburger');
        var Western=document.getElementById('Western');
        var Veggie=document.getElementById('VeggieBurger');
        var error = false;
        if (isNaN(document.forms[0].item.value)) {
            alert("A numeric value is required when ordering a burger.");
            error = true;
        } else {
            var Burger = parseInt(document.forms[0].item.value);
        }
        if (!error) {
            value = Burger * item_price * 1.0825;
            total.innerHTML = '$' + value
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the line that I am having trouble with, I think .item is the problem:

```
if (isNaN(document.forms[0].item.value)) {
```

The error is:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

I would like the item variable to be substituted for the value of item so that the document object calls a different item value for each itteration of the loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

document.forms[0].item is indeed your problem. I believe the property you are looking for is the elements property, which is a collection of the elements in your form. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms#Getting_an_element_from_within_a_form) for more info.

Comment: I used what you said and it worked! I can figure out the rest now that this problem is fixed. Thanks for your help, I have been trying for a little while to figure this out.